# Flutter best way to get MediaQuery.of(context).size.width and height globally

Tags: flutter, dart

Do I need to get `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` with every widget or is there a way to get it once, perhaps in `main.dart`, store it and have it available in every file and every class? Preferably without having to pass it through either. At the end of the day, it is not a value that will ever change so hopefully can get it just once.

I come from React Native and it was very easy to just run `var {width, height} = require('Dimensions').get('window');` once in the styles.js file.

Comment: I think that's not the purpose of MediaQuery. Like even if it affects every file it wont change anything if you just declare it. you actively have to use it throw out the app in different parts of it.

Comment: @key But it can be used to make a responsive design. There's no need to get the width and height again and again because they never change. Like in React Native, you just get it once and assign to variables.

Comment: Actually it changes. For example each time you rotate the screen, e.g. `Size(411.4, 683.4)` for portrait, and `Size(683.4, 411.4)` for landscape.

Answer (score 3):

One way that works for me is to use a constant file.
In `constant.dart`, I have global variables `double deviceWidth`, `double deviceHeight`

[image],

Before you use it for the first time, make sure you initialize them in the first widget with a build context.

[image]

Then you can import `constant.dart` into every view that needs the `MediaQuery` size and use the `deviceHeigth and`deviceWidth` variable that was declared